# assistance with javascript regexp to replace string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have some javascript that I need assistance with where I want to update a string with javascript.

Original string:

```
987654321-200x200-1_This+is+text.jpg
```

Want it to end up to be:

```
not_found-200x200.jpg
```

So `987654321` gets replaced with not_found and `-1_This+is+text` with nothing.

Note the original string is fully dynamic with only the `- x - _ +` constant in all.

I have tried something like this:

```
'987654321-200x200-1_This+is+text.jpg'.replace(/\_\d{0,}[A-Za-z]*/, '_not_found')
```

but need help with the regexp to achieve this. Anyone help?

Comment: Why don't you split on `-` and take the second array item?

Comment: @JaredFarrish - my thoughts exactly !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this will do, but if all you're looking for is `200x200` you could just split on `-` and use that :

```
var str = '987654321-200x200-1_This+is+text.jpg';
var not = 'not_found-' + str.split('-')[1] + '.jpg';
```

Comment: Boo. Too slow. I had: `['not_found-', '987654321-200x200-1_This+is+text.jpg'.split('-')[1], '.jpg'].join('')`